Computer was running until accidentally plugging speakers absent external power into the line in jack. No boot, what happened?
I built a new PC and everything was working. After swapping parts (continued working) I noticed that my AUX jack from the speakers had broken. I couldn’t splice because it had broken in the middle of the jack itself so I stupidly tried whatever came to mind unaware of potential consequences.
My speaker system has two speakers that plug into a bigger bass speaker using a similar aux jack. The bass speaker has external power that normally feeds into the small speakers in normal use. I unplugged the speakers from the bass speaker so they’d have no power supply and plugged them into the speaker jack - nothing happened. Curious, I plugged them into the microphone jack - computer turns off immediately and will not turn back on. Replaced old cpu:
Using old cpu or new one, PSU and CPU fans start but external fans don’t, light for cpu alongside header power light flash simultaneously once but fan rgb don’t, then everything goes dark while fans continue running slowly. Recently replaced PSU with 700W instead of the previous 500W because at 500W I recently experienced random shutdowns after adding fans so I removed drives to limit power draw. After hooking up new psu:
The cpu light flashed once and turned off. No fans for cpu or psu started. No header light flashed with the cpu light and I can’t even get the cpu light to flash on reboot attempts. Only thing left imo is motherboard but my experience detailed above proves I know nothing and have no authority to dictate such a limit.
Anyone know what happened or what I should replace? Sorry for length, place who referred me here asked for more details.

@john, the OP said the speakers were unpowered.  Also surely the headphone jack would be designed to prevent damage from static electricity?

John you have summarized what it took me many dollars to consider an issue. Do you know whether me using any other new parts with broken motherboard circuitry could cause the new parts to break as well? Like assuming only motherboard was initially wrong, that motherboard couldn’t have ruined my new or old psu or cpu, could it? Hoping to return parts or complete a build for sale if possible.

Well one sec let me clarify, your comment says specifically I plugged the powered speakers into the jack - they did not have power. The only aux jack I had in tact would be the one that jacks into the big speaker via intermediary audio controller. What got plugged in would be the unpowered two speakers and I guess specifically the controller to limit those speakers. Does your answer apply if what I said is true? Not sure what is denoted by {[ powered] speakers}

I suppose I can always verify as long as stuff runs after new mobo. Sorry for bothering you but I appreciate your insight and knowledge. I was starting to panic since motherboard was my last guess. All clear to your last edit

Update to follow in a day after new mobo arrives. I always knew gigabyte was the cheap version.

You plugged in the wrong device into the microphone jack. You can’t blame the manufacturer for it failing

Re Gigabyte comment: This is on you, not Gigabyte. Perhaps if you're prone to this sort of error, purchasing a UD model board from Gigabyte may be a good option. These contain a significantly higher volume of copper in the board construction, meaning the board is better able to handle abnormal and accidental voltages across the board surface than other boards.

ALRIGHT SO I WOULD LIKE TO SAY: Obviously motherboard fixed the problem. Not much else I could change. That said, what went wrong I do not know. The wiring for my whole speaker system goes: Bass speaker has 2 fixed wires (ext. power and wired remote) and one unfixed (audio jack with a split for each small speaker). Wired remote is what wires to the pc during normal use. It has an in an out but everything is fixed. Outlet goes to audio jack for PC and inlet comes from fixer wiring to the bass speaker. Conclusion: no power surge caused the issue. It was one of the deities I’ve angered.
